# SQL - How to list cells with value greater then another cell?

Tags: sql

I have the following database, and I need to list all subno, subname where the quota is greater than the quota of subno 30012.

```
subno   subname                 quota
30006   Adv Database design 300
30007   Software fundamentals   200
30008   Application Development 350
30010   Database development    300
30011   System design           200
30012   Requirement engineering 350
```

I know I can do

```
select subno, subname from subject
where quota > 350
```

but how do I change this to allow for the quota to be greater than 30012's quota rather than greater than 350?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a subquery:

```
select subno, subname from subject
where quota > (select quota from subject where subno = 30012)
```

This assumes that there is only one possible quote for a given `subno`.  If more than one is possible, then use an aggregation function, such as:

```
select subno, subname
from subject
where quota > (select max(quota) from subject where subno = 30012)
```